# Data to be updated in database if it exists - else it should insert new records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, automation

I have created an insert statement to add data to DB if data not exists.

```sql
INSERT INTO SampleList(SampleId, Type, Description)
    SELECT nr.SampleId, nr.Type, nr.Description
      FROM (VALUES (1,'A','AA'),
                 (2,'B','BB'),
                 (3,'C','CC'),
                 (4,'D','DD')
           ) AS nr (SampleId,Type,Description) 
      LEFT JOIN SampleList cr ON cr.SampleId = nr.SampleId 
      WHERE cr.SampleId IS NULL
```

But I want to update the rows as well if data exists in the database.

Can you please help me to do so?

Comment: This is called a [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Tried this. But not functioning

Comment: Can you show us your attempt in the question? What does "not functioning" mean?

Comment: MERGE SampleList cr
    USING (SELECT nr.SampleId, nr.Type, nr.Description
      FROM (VALUES (1,'A','AA'),
                 (2,'B','BB'),
                 (3,'C','CC'),
                 (4,'D','DD')
           ) as nr (SampleId, Type, Description))
ON (cr.SampleId=nr.SampleId)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        cr.Type=nr.Type,
        cr.Description=nr.Description
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (SampleId, Type, Description)
         VALUES (nr.SampleId, nr.Type, nr.Description)

Comment: above command is saying a syntax error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: *Can you show us your attempt in the **question**"*. That comment is impossible to read easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` :

```
MERGE SampleList cr 
USING (SELECT nr.SampleId, nr.[Type], nr.[Description] 
       FROM (VALUES (1,'A','AA'), (2,'B','BB'), (3,'C','CC'), (4,'D','DD') 
                  ) as nr (SampleId, [Type], [Description])
      ) AS nr -- Use missed alias
       ON (cr.SampleId = a.SampleId) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET cr.[Type] = nr.[Type], cr.[Description] = nr.[Description] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
     INSERT (SampleId, [Type], [Description]) 
        VALUES (nr.SampleId, nr.[Type], nr.[Description]); -- to terminate the merge
```

However, you can simplify your subquery with only `values` :

```
MERGE SampleList cr 
USING ( VALUES (1,'A','AA'), (2,'B','BB'), (3,'C','CC'), (4,'D','DD') 
      ) AS nr(SampleId, [Type], [Description]) 
      ON (cr.SampleId = a.SampleId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET cr.[Type] = nr.[Type], cr.[Description] = nr.[Description] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
     INSERT (SampleId, [Type], [Description]) 
        VALUES (nr.SampleId, nr.[Type], nr.[Description]); -- to terminate the merge
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is functioning as expected. you made my day